# Unable to install 'stringr' library for office work/

Tags: r

Community,

We are working with one r-script which was developed in R-3.5.3 Version and I am trying to run that script with different version R- 4.2 here I am getting below error, could you please help me to resolve this issue.

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Surendra Sai.

Comment: Seems like the problem is with the CRAN mirror you use. You can change it in Tools --> Global Options --> Packages

Comment: we tried CRAN mirror it also didn't work